# Function inside Context Hook not been called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

I am trying to implement a `signin` method, by using the context hook, but it is not been executed inside the **AuthContext** file.

Neither the `console.log` nor the `setUser` are been executed inside `signin` method of **AuthContext** file when called from `Home Page`.

How could I make it work?

below is the file **_app.tsx**

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import {AuthProvider} from '../contexts/AuthContext'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}
```

below is the file **AuthContext.tsx**

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

type AuthContextType = {
  user: FirebaseUserAuth | null;
  signin: (email: string, password: string) => void
}

const initialValue: AuthContextType= {
  user: null,
  signin: (email: string, password: string) => {}
}

export const AuthContext = createContext(initialValue);

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: PropsWithChildren) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseUserAuth | null>(initialValue.user)

  const signin = (email: string, password: string) => {
    console.log("SIGNIN FROM AUTHCONTEXT")
    setUser({
      uid: "a",
      email: "b",
      name: "c"
    })
    
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider 
      value={{
        user,
        signin
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

below is the file **index.tsx**

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { FormEvent, useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext'

const Home: NextPage = () => {

  const { user, signin } = useContext(AuthContext)

  function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const email = e.currentTarget.email.value
    const password = e.currentTarget.password.value
    console.log(email, password)
    signin(email, password)
    
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>User: {user?.name}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name='email' id='email'/>
        <input type="text" name='password' id='password'/>
        <button type='submit'>SignIn</button>
      </form>
      
    </>
  )
}
export default Home
```

**EDIT**

The folder structure is like below and the issue only happens when some folders (**context, pages, styles**) are moved into the **src** folder.

```
Project
-- .next
-- node_modules
-- public
-- src
  |-- context
  |-- pages
  |-- styles
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try deleting the `.next` folder, and re-running the dev server.

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the `.next` folder and re-running the dev server solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you miss to wrap the component with the provider

```
import { NextPage } from 'next'
import { FormEvent, useContext } from 'react'
import { AuthContext, AuthProvider } from '../contexts/AuthContext'

const Home: NextPage = () => {

  const { user, signin } = useContext(AuthContext)

  function handleSubmit(e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const email = e.currentTarget.email.value
    const password = e.currentTarget.password.value
    console.log(email, password)
    signin(email, password)
    
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>User: {user?.name}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name='email' id='email'/>
        <input type="text" name='password' id='password'/>
        <button type='submit'>SignIn</button>
      </form>
      
    </>
  )
}

const App = () => (
  <AuthProvider>
    <Home>
  </AuthProvider>
)

export default App
```

Comment: I think all the routes (including Home) are in: `<Component {...pageProps} />` in the **_app.tsx** file

Comment: I've found the source of the issue. The issue only occurs when I move some folders into the **src** folder. How to make all work inside the **src** folder